# Question marked as duplicate how to contact the people to explain why it is not?

Tags: support

I think that the following question is marked as duplicate but it should not: [Problems to login in Ubuntu 14.04 after new update (Friday)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845985/problems-to-login-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-new-update-friday)

I have not found a way to contact the people who marked it as duplicate.
Indeed, the other answers do not solve the issue and according to me the issue raised by this question is related to a recent upgrade of the nvidia driver.

Thanks for your help as I am a beginner on askubuntu.

Answer (score 6):

If you feel a question was incorrectly closed, then you should do precisely what you did: post here, on Meta. Since 5 people (or one mod/gold badge holder) considered it a dupe, the best way to change that is to make your case to the community and see if others agree with you.

You can also join the main [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and discuss the question with other users.

If you have a similar problem and the dupe's solution doesn't asolve it for you, then post a new question. Make sure to link to the duplicate and explain that you tried the suggestions there, explain how they failed and ask for a different solution.

In this case, I can't really see why you don't consider it a dupe. Perhaps you could explain in more detail?

Comment: Indeed, I tried the solution of the other article, but it does not work in my case. I really think that the newest nvidia driver is making the assumption that systemctl is present on the machine (which is not the case on 14.04 as far as I can see).